# Prove that $6^a-7^a+2\cdot 4^a-3^a-5^a\ge0$ for $-\frac{1}{2}\le a\le0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that 
           $6^a-7^a+2\cdot 4^a-3^a-5^a\ge0$ for $-\frac{1}{2}\le a\le0$.

I tried to do it by first derivative test but derivative become more complicated (same with 2nd derivative for convexity). 
Here is it's [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%206%5Ex-7%5Ex%2B2*4%5Ex-3%5Ex-5%5Ex%20from%20-1%2F2%20to%200).

Comment: Does [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B%28%286%5Ex%2B2*4%5Ex%29%2F3%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%2C+%28%287%5Ex%2B3%5Ex%2B5%5Ex%29%2F3%29%5E%281%2Fx%29+%7D%2C+x%3D-0.7..0) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  $a\in[-\frac12,0)$ and $x>0$ let $$g_a(x)=x^a-(x+1)^a-(x+3)^a$$
Then  $$f(a)=g_a(4)-g_a(3)$$
By the Mean Value Theorem this equals $g_a'(\theta)=ag_{a-1}(\theta)$ for some $\theta\in [3,4]$.  We have
$$\begin{align}\frac{g_{a-1}(\theta)}{\theta^{a-1}}&=1-(1+\tfrac1\theta)^{a-1}-(1+\tfrac3\theta)^{a-1}\\&\le 1-(1+\tfrac13)^{a-1}-2^{a-1}&\text{(negative exponent $\Rightarrow$ maximize $\tfrac1\theta$)}\\
&\le 1-(\tfrac43)^{-3/2}-2^{-3/2}&\text{(bases $>1$ $\Rightarrow$ minimize neg. exponent)}\\
&=\tfrac18\left(8-3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2\right).\end{align} $$
We have $5<3\sqrt 3<6$ and $2<1\sqrt 2<3$, therefore the sign of the expression in parenthesis is not *immediately* clear (without using a calculator). But the conjugates $8+3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2$, $8-3\sqrt3+2\sqrt 2$, $8+3\sqrt3+2\sqrt 2$ are all definitely positive (in fact $>8+2-6=4$).
The product of all four conjugates however is
$$\begin{align}&(8-3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2)(8-3\sqrt3+2\sqrt 2)(8+3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2)(8+3\sqrt3+2\sqrt 2)\\=\:&\bigl((8-3\sqrt 3)^2-8\bigr)\bigl((8+3\sqrt 3)^2-8\bigr)\\=\:&(83-48\sqrt 3)(83+48\sqrt 3)\\=\:&83^2-3\cdot 48^2\\
=\:&{-23}.\end{align} $$
We conclude $8-3\sqrt 3-2\sqrt 2<0$, so that
$$f(a)=ag_{a-1}(\theta)\ge a\theta^{a-1}\tfrac18\left(8-3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2\right)>0 $$
for $-\frac12\le a<0$.

Comment: Enjoyed with your solution. Shouldn't the 2nd line from the bottom be $f(a)=ag_{a-1}(\theta)\ge a\theta^{a-1}\tfrac18\left(8-3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2\right)>0 $ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Indeed, thanks

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you for your help.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thank you too.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have one more question this sort of please help me.

Comment: @MuhammadCamran It appears that this is your most recent question ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is a very nice proof. I do not understand the way of using four conjugate to prove $8-3\sqrt3-2\sqrt 2 < 0$ (you take 9 lines to prove it).  Why not just: $64 < 27 + 8 + 12\sqrt{6}$ or $29 < 12\sqrt{6}$ (one or two lines is enough).

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that 
$$\left((3^x+7^x+5^x)/3\right)^{1/x} > \left((6^x+4^x+4^x)/3\right)^{1/x}\hbox{ for }-0.5\le x<0$$ "as it may be seen from [the plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B%28%283%5Ex%2B7%5Ex%2B5%5Ex%29%2F3%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%2C%28%286%5Ex%2B4%5Ex%2B4%5Ex%29%2F3%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%7D%2C+x%3D-0.7..0)".
It's not too hard to test that 
$$\hbox{(1) }4.57 < \left((3^{-\frac{1}{2}}+7^{-\frac{1}{2}}+5^{-\frac{1}{2}})/3\right)^{-2} $$
$$\hbox{(2) }\left((6^{-\frac{1}{4}}+4^{-\frac{1}{4}}+4^{-\frac{1}{4}})/3\right)^{-4} < 4.57$$
$$\hbox{(3) }\sqrt[3]{6\cdot 4\cdot 4} < \left((3^{-\frac{1}{4}}+7^{-\frac{1}{4}}+5^{-\frac{1}{4}})/3\right)^{-4}$$
So, using [Generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality) we have
$$M_x(6,4,4)< M_{-\frac{1}{4}}(6,4,4)<M_{-\frac{1}{4}}(4.57,4.57,4.57)=$$
$$M_{-\frac{1}{2}}(4.57,4.57,4.57)<M_{-\frac{1}{2}}(3,5,7)\le M_x(3,5,7)\ \forall x:-\frac{1}{2}\le x<-\frac{1}{4},$$
$$M_x(6,4,4)\le M_0(6,4,4)<M_{-\frac{1}{4}}(3,5,7)<M_x(3,5,7)\ \forall x:-\frac{1}{4}\le x<0.$$

Comment: May I ask you how did you define $\frac{1}{x}$ in the power, espacially that  $x \leq 0$, so for $x=0$ this is problematic  !!

Comment: We don't need $x=0$ to include, for $x=0$ the original equation clearly holds as $1-1+2\cdot 1 - 1 - 1 =0$. Or is that the question about a real power definition? @Nizar

Comment: Okay I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

**Another way.**

It suffices to prove that, for all $a\in [-1/2, 0]$,
\begin{align*}
 6^a - \frac25\cdot  5^a - \frac35 \cdot 7^a &\ge 0, \tag{1}\\
 2\cdot 4^a - 3^a - \frac35 \cdot 5^a - \frac25 \cdot 7^a &\ge 0.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
(*Note*: Adding them up, we get the desired inequality.)

We use the Bernoulli inequality to prove (1) and (2).
Bernoulli inequality: $(1 + x)^r \le 1 + rx$
for all $x > -1$ and $0 \le r \le 1$.

- (1) is written as
  $$1 - \frac25 \cdot \left(\frac65\right)^{-a}
  - \frac35 \cdot \left(\frac67\right)^{-a} \ge 0.$$
  By Bernoulli inequality, it suffices to prove that
  $$1 - \frac25 \cdot \left(1 + \frac15\cdot (-a)\right)
  - \frac35 \cdot \left(1 - \frac17\cdot (-a)\right) \ge 0$$
  or
  $$\frac{1}{175}\cdot (-a) \ge 0$$
  which is true.
- (2) is written as
  $$2 - \left(\sqrt{\frac43}\right)^{-2a} - \frac35 \cdot \left(\frac45\right)^{-a} - \frac25\cdot \left(\sqrt{\frac47}\right)^{-2a} \ge 0.$$
  By Bernoulli inequality, it suffices to prove that
  \begin{align*}
   &2 - \left[1 + \left(\sqrt{\frac43} - 1\right)\cdot (-2a)\right] - \frac35 \cdot \left(1 - \frac15\cdot (-a)\right) \\[6pt]
   &\qquad - \frac25\cdot \left[1 + \left(\sqrt{\frac47} - 1\right)\cdot (-2a)\right] \ge 0
  \end{align*}
  or
  $$\frac{1533 - 700\sqrt{3} - 120\sqrt{7}}{525} \cdot (-a) \ge 0$$
  which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score -2):

$f(a) = 6^a - 7^a + 2 \cdot 4^a - 3^a - 5^a$.

- Value of function

$f(-1/2) = 0.00572$, and $f(0) = 0$.

- First derivative:

$2^{2 + 2 a} Log[2] - 3^a Log[3] - 5^a Log[5] + 6^a Log[6] - 7^a Log[7]$.

Evaluated at $a = -1/2$ and $0$:

${d f(a) \over d a} |_{a=-1/2} = 0.02825$ and ${d f(a) \over d a} |_{a=0} = -0.0896$.

- Second derivative:

${d^2 f(a) \over d a} = 2^{2 a+3} \log ^2(2)-3^a \log ^2(3)-5^a \log ^2(5)+6^a \log ^2(6)-7^a \log ^2(7)$

which is always negative in the range $-1/2 \leq a \le 0$.  We know this because the second derivative is negative at each end of the range and the third derivative is always negative (as can be seen on a plot).

QED.

Comment: why the second derivative is always negative in that range  ?

Comment: I think it is easier to say that $6^a-7^a+2.4^a-3^a-5^a \geq 0$ than saying  the seocnd derivative(which involve log) is negative .

Comment: "can be sen from the plot" would apply to "$f$ itself, wouldn't it?